# Compute the most frequent digit in a string of digits in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to compute the most frequent digit in a string of characters, and I need to use pointers but I am not sure how to go about this with pointers.

```
int most(char* string){
    int counter = 0;
    int* array =(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    char* original = string;
    while(*original){
        counter++;
        string++;
        //Not sure what to put in this loop
    }
}
```

for example, I want to call the code

```
char nums[] = "132433423";
printf("%d \n",most(nums));
// 3
```

Comment: Similar to a character frequency program. Initialize an array of 10 digits, loop through `num`, and find the greatest member.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my post with what I have so far but I don't understand pointers enough to get farther.

Comment: Can you do it without using pointers?

Comment: Hint: if you have a `char *` value like `string` in your code above, the formula `*string - '0'` gives you the index into your `array` variable above to accumulate the frequency.

Comment: Sorry, in C no non-trivial program can be written without using or understanding pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The specification for your function is incomplete:

- can the string contain non-digit characters?
- what should be returned if there are no digits at all?
- which value should be returned if there are multiple digits with the same maximum number of occurrences?
- should the function return the digit or its numeric value? Your `main()` function uses the latter, but it is not clear from the text of the question.

The `most` function receives a pointer to the string. You can write a loop where you handle one character at a time and increment the pointer for the next iteration until you reach the end of the string. You must also decide what to return if the string contains no digits.

Here is a simple example:

```
int most(const char *s) {
    int count[10] = { 0 };
    int res, i, max;

    while (*s) {
        if (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
            count[*s - '0']++;
        s++;
    }
    res = -1;  /* return -1 if no digits */
    max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (count[i] > max)
            res = i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

If you are restricted from using any array at all, allocating a block of memory seems indeed a good solution:

```
int most(const char *s) {
    int *count = calloc(sizeof(*count), 10);
    int res, i, max;

    while (*s) {
        if (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
            *(count + *s - '0') += 1;
        s++;
    }
    res = -1;  /* return -1 if no digits */
    max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (*(count + i) > max)
            res = i;
    }
    free(count);
    return res;
}
```

The notation `*(count + *s - '0') += 1` works this way: `count` is a pointer to an array of `int` allocated and initialized to `0` by `calloc`. `*s - '0'` is the digit value n of the character pointed to by `s`, that has been tested to be a digit. `count + *s - '0'` is a pointer to the n-th entry in the array. `*(count + *s - '0') += 1` increments this value by one.

There are ways to do this without memory allocation, with 10 variables and explicit tests for the different digits, but I doubt this be the expected solution.

If you can explain your choices to your teacher, there are 2 ways to use arrays without the `[` and `]` characters. These are obsolescent features of the C Standard, which most programmers are not familiar with, and which you can ignore unless you are curious:

```
int most(const char *s) {  /* version with C99 digraphs */
    int count<:10:> = { 0 };
    int res, i, max;

    while (*s) {
        if (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
            count<:*s - '0':>++;
        s++;
    }
    res = -1;  /* return -1 if no digits */
    max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (count<:i:> > max)
            res = i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Or

```
int most(const char *s) {  /* version with old-style trigraphs */
    int count??(10??) = { 0 };
    int res, i, max;

    while (*s) {
        if (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
            count??(*s - '0'??)++;
        s++;
    }
    res = -1;  /* return -1 if no digits */
    max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (count??(i??) > max)
            res = i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @Mulliganaceous: modern compilers may make assumptions about the `strlen` function, implement it inline, and may be able to determine that you do not modify the string inside the loop, so the code might not be too slow, but you should not rely on such advanced optimisations. There is no need to compute the length of the string at all, just test if `s[i]` is a null terminator to stop the loop.

Comment: what is this line of code doing?: free(count);
And also I am getting a little lost at this:  *(count + *s - '0')++;
Do you think you could clarify a little bit? im sorry im very new to C and pointers

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I definitely need more help understanding pointers.

Comment: Your second example is not compilable. `count = calloc(sizeof(*count), 10);` should be `*count = calloc(sizeof(*count), 10);`

Comment: @jwdonahue: good catch! answer updated, definitely more readable and less error prone on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "using pointers", but here's a version which *doesn't* use pointers except for walking the input string:

```
char most_frequent_character(char *s)
  {
  int freq[10];
  int max_freq;
  int max_idx;
  int idx;

  while(*s)
    freq[*s++ - '0']++;  /* compute character freqs */

  max_idx = 0;
  max_freq = freq[0];

  for(idx = 1 ; idx < 10 ; ++idx)
    if(freq[idx] > max_freq)
      {
      max_freq = freq[idx];
      max_idx = i;
      }

  return '0' + max_idx;
  }
```

Have fun.

---

## EDIT

To convert the above to "use pointers":

A. Change `freq` to a pointer-to-int and initialize it using `malloc`; in addition, initialize the memory pointed to by `freq` using `memset`:

```
int *freq = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
memset(freq, 0, sizeof(int)*10);
```

B. In the "compute character freqs" loop, use pointer references instead of indexing:

```
while(*s)
  {
  *(freq + (*s - '0')) = *(freq + (*s - '0')) + 1;
  s++;
  }
```

C. Use a pointer ref to set the initial value of `max_freq`:

```
max_freq = *freq;
```

D. In the `for` loop, use pointer math instead of indexing:

```
  for(idx = 1 ; idx < 10 ; ++idx)
    if( *(freq + idx) > max_freq)
      {
      max_freq = *(freq + idx);
      max_idx = i;
      }
```

E. Free the memory allocated earlier before the return statement:

```
free(freq);
return '0' + max_idx;
```

Now, sit down and understand why things are done in the way that they are here. For example, why *didn't* I do the following when computing the character frequencies?

```
while(*s++)
  *(freq + (*s - '0')) = *(freq + (*s - '0')) + 1;
```

or

```
while(*s)
  *(freq + (*s++ - '0')) = *(freq + (*s++ - '0')) + 1;
```

Each of the above would save several lines of code - why shouldn't they be used? (The obvious answer is "because they won't work as intended" - but WHY?)

Best of luck.

Comment: what I mean is that I am not allowed to use arrays. Unfortunately I cannot use any brackets in my code. This is what is causing me problems because I know how to do this problem with arrays. I am not sure how to describe my problem better I am sorry if I am not articulating it well

Comment: If the string has non-digit characters this code will fault. The function name `most_frequent_characters` implies that any character might be encountered.

Comment: @30278560387 Didn't they teach you that `a[x]` is equivalent to `*(a+x)` before giving the assignment? You can always translate any array expression to pointers like that.

Comment: You'll want to initialize `freq` before incrementing its elements.

Comment: @30278560387 - OK, I added examples of how to convert to the code to eliminate array indexing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string.h>    
int most (char* nums) {
    int i, max_index = 0;
    int digit_dictionary[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    for (i=0; i< strlen(nums); i++) {
        digit_dictionary[nums[i]-'0'] ++;
    }

    for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
        if (digit_dictionary[i]> digit_dictionary[max_index])
            max_index = i;
    }
    return max_index;
}
```

I will try to be as elaborate as I can:
You create a dictionary  in which each index corresponds to a digit that can occur (0-9). Then, iterate through the string(which is basically an array of characters, and store each digit to its corresponding index in dictionary.

**Note**: `[nums[i]-'0']` is calculated into the index of the dictionary since each char has an integer value (look up ASCII table). 
The counter at that index is incremented to keep count of number of occurrences of that digit.

After that, go through the dictionary to determine at which position is the digit with most occurrences, and return that digit.

Answer (score 0):

You could first sort the string so that the smaller digit characters appear first in `num`. You could use [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) (from `stdlib.h`) like

```
int cmpfn(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int x = *(char *)a;
    int y = *(char *)b;
    return x-y;
}
int main()
{
    char nums[] = "132433423";//"111222223333";//
    qsort(nums, sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]) -1, sizeof(nums[0]), cmpfn);
    printf("\nAfter sorting: %s", nums);

    . . . . . . . . . . 
    . . . . . . . . . . 

}
```

Declare variables to store the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) (ie, the value that appears most frequently in the data) and the frequency of the mode value.

```
int mode=-1, modecount=-1, n;
```

Now find the frequency of each digit character. Since this is a sorted character array, the same value will appear consecutively.

```
for(char *ptr=nums, *lptr=NULL; *ptr; ptr+=n)
{
    lptr = strrchr(ptr, *ptr);
    n = lptr - ptr + 1;
    if(n>modecount)
    {
        printf("\n%c", *ptr);
        modecount = n;
        mode = *ptr;
    }
}   
printf("\nMode is: %c", mode);
```

[`strrchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) (from `string.h`) will find the last occurrence of a character in a string.

Comment: testing for `strrchr(ptr, *ptr) != NULL` seems redundant.

Comment: You could also use a nested loop: `for (n = 1; ptr[n] == *ptr; n++);` and get rid of `lptr`

Comment: @chqrlie Oops! Placed it back.